# Using Android App Bundle for an app that has a 61MB expansion file

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, android-app-bundle

I'm currently looking at using the new App Bundle feature for an app that is already published.

The app has a size of 13MB but uses an expansion file of 61MB to store an audio sample library (a collection of static audio files) that is mandatory for the app.

First reason for that is that when I first developed the app, the app size limit was 50MB. But most importantly, this is working out nicely because when the app is updated, users are only downloading the 13MB APK file as the .obb expansion file doesn't need to be updated.

I now would like to use an Android Bundle to reduce the APK size by splitting density, but this feature is apparently not compatible with OBB files.

I could put the audio sample library in the Android Bundle, but if I understand correctly, that audio library would be downloaded each time a user updates the app?

Is there a way to achieve the "best of both worlds" by providing an Android Bundle but avoid the download of the library at each update?

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store serves patches of APKs for updates (i.e. only the difference between the version currently on device and the newest version being installed), so if that big file doesn't change, the update will be small.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The 13MB APK is always served as an approximately 10MB download, even when I change only a line of code between two builds.

Comment: Patches are only generated if enough users request this version to be installed, so the first few users may still get the full APK.

Comment: So the first few users (first few thousands?) would have to re-download the whole library at each update if I switch to an Android Bundle. Not an option then :(

Comment: Few dozens, yes.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. Do you have a source for this? I remember having read something saying that this optimization will only be applied to popular apps (whatever that means), but I can't find it again.

Comment: I don't know about any documentation, I know it was mentioned informally in some conferences: Google Play just serves the smallest thing possible to users based on several different factors which may vary per app and per device (and it's not limited to just popular apps).

Comment: Thank you. But I never had an optimized download for any of my published apps on my various devices. Always the full APK size (with a little compression). Can't risk it based on informal mentions in conferences and make updates that are 60 MB!